# no HDMI sound in Ubuntu 17 with Kabini Audio driver

Tags: sound, 17.04, asus, hdmi, amd-graphics

I have an asus X55QG with Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. The HDMI video works well but there is no sound when HDMI output is selected. I have tried some solutions in internet, but none worked, including

- adding radeon.audio = 1 to grub config
- and adding option options snd-hda-intel model=auto to /etc/modprobe/alsa-base.conf
- installing pavucontrol and adjusting different profiles for HDMI
- installing alsamixer
- killing pulseaudio daemon

I have noted that alsamixer with text interface, when I select HDMI card only shows SPDIF but there is no way to modify volume.

my driver is listed with inxi:

```
inxi -Fzx -c 0
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 157a driver: 
snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:09.2
       Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio 
driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:01.1
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-38-generic
```

I don't know why but graphic seems to interfere with sound so I have listed too:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Carrizo bus-ID: 00:01.0
       Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 
8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
       bus-ID: 03:00.0
       Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 driver: N/A Resolution: 
1366x768@60.00hz
       GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CARRIZO (DRM 3.9.0 / 4.10.0-38-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)
       GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you connecting the HDMI to?  The only reason I ask this is that I have a monitor that has HDMI on it, but the built in speakers are not connected to HDMI and only work on the stereo input jack.

Comment: I have a Samsung Smart TV with HDMI port. I have proved the HDMI port with Debian and other laptops  and works perfectly, but not with this version of Ubuntu.